# mongoose limit and return from a specific index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
var q = models.Post.find({published: true}).sort({'date': -1}).limit(20);
q.exec(function(err, posts) {
     // `posts` will be of length 20
});
```

The total amount of `posts` is let's say ~200, I want to limit the result by 20 and sort by date, but also return from a specified index, ie `50`

Index isn't currently stored as a key in the model, would greatly appreciate a solution to set the index via a query.

Thanks

**Edit**

Solution:

```
Model.find({published: true}, fields, {skip: 10, limit: 10}).sort({'date': -1});
```

Comment: What indexes you have on this collection?

Comment: Found the solution from another question. Guess I didn't search properly.